# Do XML parsers tell the difference between xsi:nil="true" and omitted elements?

Tags: xml, wcf, jaxb, nullable, minoccurs

Are XML parsers/deserializers in general able to tell the difference between [nillable elements explicitly set to null and optional elements that are left out](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-null/index.html)?

Assume that we have the following complex type:

```
<complexType name="NiceType">
  <sequence>
    <element name="niceElem" nillable="true" type="int" minOccurs="0" />
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Element explicitly set to null (example 1):

```
<niceType>
  <niceElem xsi:nil="true"/> 
</niceType>
```

Element omitted (example 2):

```
<niceType>
</niceType>
```

Would parsers in general, such as JAX-B implementations or .NET alikes such as the XML module of WCF, be able to tell the difference between example 1 and example 2 above? In other words, would you in an interoperable manner be able to combine both NULL representations - as in the example - in order to communicate different shades of NULL?

Comment: Excellent wording - *"different shades of NULL"* - would make a decent band name!

Comment: A great idea, somewhat nerdie band but anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

XML parsers (e.g. `XmlReader`, `XmlDocument`, `XDocument`) don't treat `xsi:nil` specially - you still see the element in the stream/document.

`XmlSerializer` does handle `xsi:nil`: within that context it means the same thing as an omitted node; you can make WCF serialize using `XmlSerializer` by marking your `DataContract`s using `XmlSerializerFormatterAttribute`.

`DataContractSerializer` does use the attribute: however I am not sure what all the rules are for it to use them (one case is [circular references](http://blog.stuartwhiteford.com/?tag=datacontractserializer)) - it is much more likely to omit elements. I don't think you should pass `xsi:nil` to `DataContractSerializer` unless it uses it in that case - as `DataContractSerializer` is designed around assumptions to improve de/serialization performance.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil) it looks like it was originally designed to work like the JavaScript `null` and `undefined` - where `null` (`xsi:nil`) is a valid value and `undefined` (omitted) is the entire non-existence of a value; especially with complex types - you can provide the element but omit it's content (even if the content is required according to the schema).

In general I would avoid it. It's non-intuitive - I don't think I have seen a REST/SOAP API out there that uses it (except InfoPath which uses it exclusively); most just use `null = undefined`. The xmlns declaration and usage of it also eat a few extra valuable bytes.

*Bonus Marks:* If you make an element optional and it isn't nullable (e.g. `xsd:int`) the C# generator provides a `<Name>Specified` property - you can add your own properties like this. This would allow you to differentiate between `xsi:nil` and omittance (nil when specified and null, omitted when not specified). However, this only works with `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: The reason to why I would like to combine nillable="true" and minOccurs="0" is to be able to send update messages (in web service calls) in which you can distinguish between which elements to NOT update, and which to update and which to delete. Elements not to be updated would, in that design, be omitted. Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709715/how-to-use-optional-attributes-in-web-service-update-messages-dtos). Your input makes me doubt on that approach.

Comment: How about: `<update xmlns:sync="http://foo"><item id="100"><node1 sync:action="delete" /><node2 sync:action="update" /></item></update>`. I personally think `xsi:nil` is smelly; for the exact same reason you had to ask a question about it: it's unclear what exactly it means; and API support is spotty at best. The bonus marks bit will sort you out though (in addition to `XmlSerializerFormatter`).

Comment: Spotty API support is not a good thing in terms of SOA services. Thanks for pointing that out. It is essential that heterogeneous WS frameworks are able to parse it correctly. The proposal you make is similar to the alternative *Alt 2.1* in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709715/how-to-use-optional-attributes-in-web-service-update-messages-dtos). One argument against having action attributes in the elements could be that you clutter your "business document" types with verbs related to the operation that should be applied on them.

Comment: @nize another way to deal with it is to provide a supplementary document indicating how to apply the changes. E.g. `<package><originalRootItem><item id="1" /></originalRootItem><delta><update ref="1" /></delta></package>`.