# How to use optional attributes in web service update messages (DTOs)?

Tags: web-services, xsd, dto, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency

**BACKGROUND**

Assume you have a (SOAP) web service, `BookService`, managing books in a library. In the information model assume that the `Book` entity has the following attributes:

- `id`
- `author`
- `publisher`
- `title`
- `shelfId`

In order to manipulate the data four web service operations are defined:

- `AddBook`
- `GetBook`
- `UpdateBook`
- `DeleteBook`

Request and response message are defined for each operation. However, the design of the update message XML schemas is more complicated. We would like to achieve the following qualities:

- *R1: Possibility to reset/delete previous values of an attribute.* E.g. say that you no more will keep the book in the library and thereby would like to reset/empty/remove the attribute value of the attribute `shelfId` for that specific book.
- *R2: Avoid chattiness in the web services.* See the [anti-pattern Chatty Services](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-antipatterns/).
- *R3: Prepare for future requirements on Concurrency Control and Optimistic Locking.* We may want to minimize (or remove) the risk of having updates made on based of old information.

**DESIGN ALTERNATIVES**

I see three mayor alternatives, of which one has several sub-options, to design the update message(s):

1. *Send the entire business document.* Left-out elements (having `minOccurs="0"` in the schema) OR elements explicitly set to null, i.e. `<shelfId xsi:nil="true"/>`, would be interpreted as deletion of the previous values.
2. *Highlight the changes or send only the diff.*

   1. Send the entire business document, but mark the modified elements using an attribute specific to this purpose. Example: `<author dirty="true">Hemingway<author/>`. The provider of the service then updates only those elements marked as dirty and ignores the other ones.
   2. In the message schema, set all elements, but the identifier `id`, to have `minOccurs="0"`. The consumer sends *only* those elements which are to be modified. A left-out element must *not* semantically be interpreted as a deletion. In order to delete a value the explicit XML `NULL` value must be used. Example: `<shelfId xsi:nil="true"/>`.
   3. Send the entire business document, but also submit a copy of the previously read document. The provider can then compare the two documents and update *only* those attributes for which the new and the previous documents differ.
3. *Define multiple operations.* Instead of only using one operation, `UpdateBook`, define multiple operation based on which elements you believe will have to be updated, e.g. `UpdateBookAuthor`, `UpdateBookPublisher` and so on. Each of these will have only mandatory elements and for removal of elements use the explicit NULL of XML, e.g. `<shelfId xsi:nil="true"/>`.

**DISCUSSION**

*Alt 3* has the advantage of being simple to understand, but the drawback is that consumers would need to invoke multiple operations in case multiple fields in the `Book` entity should be updated. This makes the service "chatty" (see R3 above), giving performance penalties.

*Alt 2* is more complex than *Alt 1*, but there are some advantages of *Alt 2* related to Optimistic Concurrency Control:

- For situations when optimistic locking with timestamps/versions for each field is stored in the database (e.g. `authorVersion` ) => *Alt 2* provides a way of letting multiple users modify different parts, such as `author` and `publisher`, of the same `Book` concurrently with less risk of having faults.
- For situations when optimistic locking with one single timestamp/version for the entire `Book` is stored in the database => No real advantage of *Alt 2* over *Alt 1*. Even if an update only modifies one field, a too old version number of the request would result in a fault.
- For situations when no concurrency control or optimistic/pessimistic locking is used => *Alt 2* gives less risk than *Alt 1* of overwriting with old data, but still other inconsistent changes may give problems.

There is yet another situation in which *Alt 2* (and *Alt 3*) gives an advantage over *Alt 1*. The consumer may not store all the data about the `Book` entity. For example, a robot picking the books from their shelf's may be programmed more effectively if it doesn't need to keep track (cache) on the information on the author, but just the shelf, when updating the shelf information.

An advantage of the approach in *Alt 2.3*, where the consumer submits entire copies of previous versions instead of version numbers or timestamps, is that no dedicated column in the database is needed for version number or timestamp.

To sum it up I would say *Alt 2.2* looks like the most attractive one for most cases. The challenge here is just that the frameworks deserializing the XML must be able to distinguish a left-out element from an element explicitly set to NULL, e.g. `<shelfId xsi:nil="true"/>`. [See a post on this topic here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774192/what-is-the-correct-way-to-represent-null-xml-elements)

**QUESTION**

Which of the alternatives would you go for? Do you see other, better alternatives? What do you think of the discussion?

Answer (score 1):

As you have already discussed, alt 2.2 seems to be rather feasible. However, the distinction between minoccurs=0 and nil is often ignored by frameworks and is also hard to understand for many users (potentially of this interface). Thus I would go for a variation, where in one change message you mark with every attribute explicitly when you want them to be nullified.

etag could be one standard to be used for optimistic locking. I think you have discussed the implications of locking mechanisms already extensively. It should work the way you describe.

Alt 1 is a lot simpler, both in message design and usage/implementation and if traffic is not an issue and optimistic locking for whole objects is enough (which is most often the case imho), that could also work well.

You should also take into account that with some business processes, changes of different attributes are interdependent so it doesn't make sense to have separate versioning for attributes, since a change at one attribute can be wrong even if only another attribute was outdated at the time of change.

If this can be the case, it is another reason for alt 1.